# Compute the date range count for every hour using a list of dates

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, lambda, java-8

1. I want the **Map<String hours, count >** from the list of dates
2. I also group by date and count for every 1 hour

Ex In DB Value looks like this

```
2023-07-18 10:10:00.000
2023-07-18 10:20:00.000
2023-07-18 11:10:00.000
2023-07-18 11:30:00.000
2023-07-18 11:35:00.000
2023-07-18 12:10:00.000
2023-07-18 12:30:00.000
```

My expected result should be as follow as should calculate each 1 hour range count

Map result

```
<10-11 ,2>
<11-12 ,3>
<12-13 ,2>
```

I tried lot of examples provide by the forum but does't work.

Comment: How is the result derived from the data? I would have expected values of 2, 3, 2 instead of 3, 3, 1. What specifically did you try and what wasn’t working? Please read [ask].

Comment: SELECT group_concat(distinct CONCAT(HOUR(date_time), '-', HOUR(date_time) + 1)) AS hour_range, COUNT(date_time) AS count
FROM your_table
GROUP BY HOUR(date_time)
ORDER BY HOUR(date_time);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are expecting <hour-range, count> in your output, following query might solve your problem -

```
SELECT group_concat(distinct CONCAT(HOUR(date_time), '-', HOUR(date_time) + 1)) AS hour_range, COUNT(date_time) AS count
FROM your_table
GROUP BY HOUR(date_time)
ORDER BY HOUR(date_time);
```

[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/EG7xD8aB)

Comment: SELECT group_concat(distinct CONCAT(HOUR(INCIDENT_TIMESTAMP_), '-', HOUR(INCIDENT_TIMESTAMP_) + 1)) AS hour_range, COUNT(INCIDENT_TIMESTAMP_) AS count
FROM act_ru_incident WHERE  INCIDENT_TIMESTAMP_ > now() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR and PROC_DEF_ID_ = 'somecontion'
GROUP BY HOUR(INCIDENT_TIMESTAMP_)
ORDER BY HOUR(INCIDENT_TIMESTAMP_);

To fetch past 8 hours record the above is fine right ? @ps-

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Yes this query should work for past  8 hours. The only suggestion is, you are grouping by hour(<field>) where I guess your assumption is that your data is only for a day. In case you want to see multiple days' data, this will mix up your hourly data between dates. Instead you should use date_format(date_time, '%Y%m%d%h') or similar to group your data. This will help you seeing accurate data across dates.

Comment: Thank you ps- 
As of now we need only one day data 
For example if date is 2023-07-19 10:01:01.000 then it should return the previous day record since we are trying to fetch last 8 hours data 

Where i need to use date_format(date_time, '%Y%m%d%h') ps ?

Comment: 24 hours back in time should not create any problem. Beyond that, you should use date_format() is what I would recommend.